# Python- tkinter: Opening One Another image in another window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, toplevel, photoimage

Hello I am doing a job that I need (from a tkinter window containing an image) call another window that contains another imagem.I tried the following:

```
from tkinter import*

def abrir1():
    b =Tk()
    imagen = PhotoImage(file= "F2.png")
    la = Label(b,image =imagen)
    la.pack()

def abrir2():
    b =Toplevel()
    imagen = PhotoImage(file= "F2.png")
    la = Label(b,image =imagen)
    la.pack() 

a = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(a, bg ="black",width = 512,height =512)
canvas.pack()

imagem = PhotoImage(file = "E2.png")
a1 = canvas.create_image(256,256,image = imagem)

btu1 = Button(a,text ="Abri1!",command = abrir1)
btu1.place(x = 150,y=400)
btu2 = Button(a,text ="Abri2!",command = abrir2)
btu2.place(x = 300,y=400)
```

But when I press the first button ( btu1 ) it returns the following error message:

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

And when when I press the second button ( btu2 ) does not happen error but does not show the image, only the new window is created ;

I've tried several ways including placing *** with canvas**  and  **without canvas***  ;

Comment: All questions on StackOverflow should be posted in English so that everyone can understand the question and provide potential solutions.

Comment: The problem is that you're creating two instances of `Tk`: `a=Tk()` and `b=Tk()`. You must only create one instance.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out so I made the function `def abir2():` creating a `Toplevel ( )` there is no problem with the second instance of tkinter. If you could suggest an alternative way I would appreciate it .

Comment: Suever 
I corrected the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

The first problem is that you are creating two instances of `Tk`. A tkinter program needs to have exactly one instance.

The second problem is that the image you are creating is saved as a local variable. When the function returns, the variable is garbage collected. When a tkinter image is garbage collected the image data is discarded even though the widget still exists.

A very basic search of the internet yields this page: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: Dude you helped me a lot .Thank you for the quick , and eficinte , answer.